# How to create a simple app/page to click on a button on another page

Tags: html, button

I would like to create a html/php page with a button that can click on the draw button on this page http://andivia.com.sg/dnd/luckydraw.html

I have this html page http://andivia.com.sg/dnd/luckydraw.html which will be displayed on a projector.
I would like to create another html/php page to trigger the buttons on the above link

```
<body>
    <h1>Lucky Draw Result</h1>
    <div id="Result">
        <span id="ResultNum">Result</span>
    </div>
    <div id="Button">
        <input type='button' value='Draw' onclick='beginRndNum(this)' />
        <input type='button' value="Confirm" onclick="skipCandidate()" style="display: none" />
    </div>
    <div class="imported">
        <table id="Data"></table>
    </div>
    <div id="Report" hidden="true">
        <ul id="messagebox"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I trigger this button from another html/php page?

When I click on the button on the newly created page, it will trigger http://andivia.com.sg/dnd/luckydraw.html to start the draw.

Answer (score 0):

**Soultion 1**

you can use concept of [websocket API,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)
if you click on button of other page you will send websocket packet. And on this page if you receive this package you can call the stop function and you will get the desired result

**Solution 2**

You can keep flag in DB, suppose True and False, if you click on button of other page you will set flag to True. On this page you will continuously hit the API to check the status of the flag. If the flag is True you can call stop function

But, first solution is good practice

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Will give it a try

Comment: Welcome @OCL upvote and accept the answer, if its satisfied answer